# How to find entire string ending with = when it contains also =

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm completely new to scala and wanted to try it. I want to parse log files generated by another tool and extract valuable information.
It is one big line with a list of metrics, with a name followed by = and a list of values, each being a name followed by = and a value enclosed between ". Counters are repeated for each kpi between |, and same goes for each kpi

My problem(s) : I can't correctly parse a line when a name contains = as I use it as end token

:

```
input : 20:53:19.503 Dbg 29999 [er-thread-1] KPI reporter: [sql.pstmt.executeQuery.select top 200 Interaction.Id, Interaction.MediaTypeId, Interaction.TypeId, Interaction.SubtypeId, Interaction.TenantId, Interaction.StartDate, Interaction.ParentId, Interaction.AllAttributes, Interaction.QueueName from Interaction where ((Interaction.TypeId = {0}) and (Interaction.MediaTypeId = {1}) and (Interaction.Status = {2}) and ((Interaction.CreatorAppId = {3}) or (Interaction.CreatorAppId = {4}))) order by Interaction.StartDate asc .tmr=[min="0.0"|m5_rate="0.099"|max="249.0"|count="1241"|p999="248.565"|p99="73.65"|mean_rate="0.099"|type="TIMER"|m15_rate="0.099"|duration_unit="MILLISECONDS"|m1_rate="0.096"|p50="0.0"|p75="15.0"|p95="16.0"|mean="6.533"|rate_unit="SECOND"|stddev="17.611"|p98="16.0"]]
```

[1.336] failure: `[' expected but` ' found

```
20:53:19.503 Dbg 29999 [er-thread-1] KPI reporter: [sql.pstmt.executeQuery.select top 200 Interaction.Id, Interaction.MediaTypeId, Interaction.TypeId, Interaction.SubtypeId, Interaction.TenantId, Interaction.StartDate, Interaction.ParentId, Interaction.AllAttributes, Interaction.QueueName from Interaction where ((Interaction.TypeId = {0}) and (Interaction.MediaTypeId = {1}) and (Interaction.Status = {2}) and ((Interaction.CreatorAppId = {3}) or (Interaction.CreatorAppId = {4}))) order by Interaction.StartDate asc .tmr=[min="0.0"|m5_rate="0.099"|max="249.0"|count="1241"|p999="248.565"|p99="73.65"|mean_rate="0.099"|type="TIMER"|m15_rate="0.099"|duration_unit="MILLISECONDS"|m1_rate="0.096"|p50="0.0"|p75="15.0"|p95="16.0"|mean="6.533"|rate_unit="SECOND"|stddev="17.611"|p98="16.0"]]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
```

Here is my current parser :

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class kpiParser extends JavaTokenParsers {

  override val whiteSpace = "".r

  def name: Parser[String] = """[\w\. -\\,\\(\\){}]+?=""".r

  def counter: Parser[Any] = name~value

  def timer: Parser[Any] = """tmr""".r
  def gauge: Parser[Any] = """gge""".r
  def count: Parser[Any] = """cnt""".r
  def meter: Parser[Any] = """mtr""".r

  def value: Parser[Any] = """""""~(decimalNumber|intNumber|stringValue)~"""""""
//  def value: Parser[Any] = """\w+""".r

  def stringValue: Parser[Any] = """\w+""".r
  def intNumber: Parser[String] = """\d+""".r

  def logLine: Parser[Any] = timeStamp~kpiReporter
  def timeStamp: Parser[Any] = """([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3})""".r
  def kpiReporter: Parser[Any] = """.* KPI reporter: \[""".r~rep(kpi|"|"~kpi)~"]"
  def kpi: Parser[Any] = name~"["~rep(counter|"|"~counter)~"]"

}

object ParseExpr extends kpiParser {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val simple2 = """20:53:19.503 Dbg 29999 [er-thread-1] KPI reporter: [evt.logic-check-listeners.tmr=[min="0.023"|m5_rate="0.018"|max="0.492"|count="211"|p999="0.492"|p99="0.328"|mean_rate="0.017"|type="TIMER"|m15_rate="0.017"|duration_unit="MILLISECONDS"|m1_rate="0.025"|p50="0.055"|p75="0.061"|p95="0.134"|mean="0.064"|rate_unit="SECOND"|stddev="0.045"|p98="0.199"]|svc.OMResponse.AddStdRespUsage.success.cnt=[count="20000"|type="COUNTER"]]"""      
    val problem = """20:53:19.503 Dbg 29999 [er-thread-1] KPI reporter: [sql.pstmt.executeQuery.select top 200 Interaction.Id, Interaction.MediaTypeId, Interaction.TypeId, Interaction.SubtypeId, Interaction.TenantId, Interaction.StartDate, Interaction.ParentId, Interaction.AllAttributes, Interaction.QueueName from Interaction where ((Interaction.TypeId = {0}) and (Interaction.MediaTypeId = {1}) and (Interaction.Status = {2}) and ((Interaction.CreatorAppId = {3}) or (Interaction.CreatorAppId = {4}))) order by Interaction.StartDate asc .tmr=[min="0.0"|m5_rate="0.099"|max="249.0"|count="1241"|p999="248.565"|p99="73.65"|mean_rate="0.099"|type="TIMER"|m15_rate="0.099"|duration_unit="MILLISECONDS"|m1_rate="0.096"|p50="0.0"|p75="15.0"|p95="16.0"|mean="6.533"|rate_unit="SECOND"|stddev="17.611"|p98="16.0"]|evt.logic-check-listeners.tmr=[min="0.023"|m5_rate="0.018"|max="0.492"|count="211"|p999="0.492"|p99="0.328"|mean_rate="0.017"|type="TIMER"|m15_rate="0.017"|duration_unit="MILLISECONDS"|m1_rate="0.025"|p50="0.055"|p75="0.061"|p95="0.134"|mean="0.064"|rate_unit="SECOND"|stddev="0.045"|p98="0.199"]|svc.OMResponse.AddStdRespUsage.success.cnt=[count="20000"|type="COUNTER"]]"""      
    // println("input : " + args(0))
    println("input : " + simple2)
    println(parseAll(logLine, simple2))
    println("input : " + complex)
    println(parseAll(logLine, complex))
    println("input : " + problem)
    println(parseAll(logLine, problem))
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `=[` as end token to distinguish it from `="` situation. Regular expression could be something like `blahblah(=)[` (see, the `[` is out of group, so it wouldn't swallowed as delimeter, but will be taken into consideration)

Comment: I tried with a definition for name like this : `def name: Parser[String] = """[\w\. -\\,\\(\\){}=]*?(=\[)""".r` but it fails : `[1.84] failure: `]' expected but `m' found ` so _evt.logic-check-listeners.tmr=[_ was used for more than name I guess

Comment: I'm doing now two definition for name, one for kpi and one for counter, like `def kpiName: Parser[String] = """[\w\. -\\,\\(\\){}=]*?=\[""".r` and `def counterName: Parser[Any] = """[\w\. -]*?=""".r` it seems to do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing two definition for name, one for my kpi and one for my counters, like this :

```
def kpiName: Parser[String] = """[\w\. -\\,\\(\\){}=]*?=\[""".r
def counterName: Parser[Any] = """[\w\. -]*?=""".r
```

I was then able to parse a name with = in it